# ASP.net Gridview Itemtemplate Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using C# ASP.net, and relative new to it, and need to accomplish below.

In my VS2010 web application project I have `webform` with a `Gridview` which fetches the data from a table.

In the Grid, I have `Commandfiled` Button (column1) and Item template with `Dropdownlist` (column2).

Use case is, user first selects one `listitem` from 3 list items (H, L and M) and then selects command button.

I am not able to figure out how to extract selected `listitem` from a selected row

```
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = GridView2.SelectedRow;
    Label4.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[4].Text + "."; 
    Label5.Text = "You selected this list item from dropdownlist " + ???? ; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridViewRow` object provides the method [**`FindControl`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) (as do all container controls) to get access to a control in the row by its id.  For example, if your `DropDownList` has an id of `MyDropDown`, you could use the following to access its selected value:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView2.SelectedRow;
DropDownList MyDropDown = row.FindControl("MyDropDown") as DropDownList;
string theValue = MyDropDown.SelectedValue;
// now do something with theValue
```

This is the recommended method for accessing all controls in your `GridView`.  You want to avoid doing things like `row.Cells[#]` as much as possible, because it easily breaks when you re-arrange or add/remove columns from your GridView.

Comment: Thank you sir for the solution and tip on avoiding cell index